# Typescript in redux reducer

Tags: typescript, redux

Following [redux guide to typescript](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript) I came up with the following code for my reducer. Typescript can't infer the right types on the switch case statement, though.

Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40758619/7502752) and its pointed [typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions), I was able to make it work using string literals on the type variable on the interface. But I don't wanna use literals in there, since I am exporting my actions strings in a Actions variable, like in the code below.

What am I missing to be able to make it work like on the redux guide?

```js
export const Action = {
  action1:'ACTION1',
  action2:'ACTION2'
}

interface actionType1 {
  type: typeof Action.action1, 
  stringPayload:string
}

interface actionType2 {
  type: typeof Action.action2,
  objectPayload:{
    str: string
  } 
}

type actionType = actionType1 | actionType2;

interface stateType {
  str:string,
}

const defaultState = {
  str:''
};


const reducer = ( state = defaultState, action:actionType) : stateType => {
  switch(action.type){
    case Action.action1:
      return {
        str:action.stringPayload //stringPayload appears as error
      }
        /*
        [ts]
        Property 'stringPayload' does not exist on type 'actionType'.
        Property 'stringPayload' does not exist on type 'actionType2'.
        */ 

    case Action.action2:
      return action.objectPayload //objectPayload appears as error
      /*
      [ts]
      Property 'objectPayload' does not exist on type 'actionType'.
      Property 'objectPayload' does not exist on type 'actionType1'
      */

    default:
      return state  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It compiles with errors, because `Action.action1`, `Action.action2` in reducer resolve to string. If you hover over your `Action` type, you can see how it's interpreted:

```
const Action: {
    action1: string;
    action2: string;
}
```

You could also test that by writing following code

```
type TestAction2Prop = typeof Action.action2 //  type TestAction2Prop = string
```

To solve that, you have to tell TypeScript explicitely that no literal types of `Action` should be widened (e.g. 'ACTION1' to string). You do that by [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
export const Action = {
  action1:'ACTION1',
  action2:'ACTION2'
}  as const
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wIIJgSxXAXjgG8AoOOAQ2z2QEYAuAcgwGEAVASQHkA5OpgBpyVGigBMzNlz7impAL4VKqRCnSlSOZDGBQAZtWCjcKdgE8wwOiRExLwBnHtWI+uFlPIAdNS91BOBF0KG0AcwAFSnMAGwhKABMGEPDFTW1dAyMTWgsrcVsKF0dnBzcPMR8-WnFhCggAIwArYGwo2PiksgoKEKcU5DCRJTTSYpyzB0IJ5DzrOAAfGbnxAG50nT1DBGN0Sl05wrg+gbDhBU0kNHgE4EMAVxiYAGUYfeMibuOYKGZ5BXWl3U8CgwAS9x2UGmAApvu9prcHk9Xu9AtUUAx0bMHABKOD9N4HKYEAB8R1QAHccDAEAALaFY7zFHFfCgIFTGTy0XyVRgiHpwUEwe5QZBHAW9H6YyreU7tOKJOAAeiVcuiCoSVDAVkoUFUKjgeig0H5PQuEp6SoAVKaBQBtGCoAC6tp6EWNVlg5jgTDVHUSTDgCQgwFUyAg8FAOHQcHw4yYWLmTG8roo7ognvsPr9GsDwdDcHDkZA0fgcamCcqK2TqbgVqVQVN7NQnJlWMkrqFIrFjMaLTa6s6yqVfdaMHlQ8o2uAuv1qiNJot1tdDudrvTme9TFHA-9CTzIbDEcNJZj5asPsTDhrFo3eiz2+aY4nAaDh8Lx6jZ7F8avVgErr1poAqIpQjwwAwnbAMKopwroFDDIoQA)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export class Action {
    static action1:'ACTION1';
    static action2:'ACTION2';
}

interface actionType1 {
    type: typeof Action.action1,
    stringPayload:string
}

interface actionType2 {
    type: typeof Action.action2,
    objectPayload:{
        str: string
    }
}

type actionType = actionType1 | actionType2;

interface stateType {
    str:string,
}

const defaultState = {
    str:''
};


const reducer = ( state = defaultState, action:actionType) : stateType => {
    switch(action.type){
        case Action.action1:
            return {
                str:action.stringPayload //stringPayload appears as error
            }
        /*
        [ts]
        Property 'stringPayload' does not exist on type 'actionType'.
        Property 'stringPayload' does not exist on type 'actionType2'.
        */

        case Action.action2:
            return action.objectPayload //objectPayload appears as error
        /*
        [ts]
        Property 'objectPayload' does not exist on type 'actionType'.
        Property 'objectPayload' does not exist on type 'actionType1'
        */

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```