# define generic redux action creator in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, redux

I'm trying to create a generic action creator type that accepts a generic action as an argument for my redux reducers:

```js
import { Action } from 'redux';

// Generic Action
interface ActionWithPayload<TType extends string, TPayload> extends Action<TType> {
  payload: TPayload;
}

// Example type using ActionWithPayload
type SetLoggedInAction = ActionWithPayload<string, boolean>;

// I have a non-generic action creator for SetLoggedInAction
type SetLoggedIn = (payload: SetLoggedInAction['payload']) => SetLoggedInAction;

// I want to make the above action creator generic, but this does not work
// throws "Type 'TAction["type"]' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'"
type GenericActionCreator<
  TAction extends ActionWithPayload<TAction['type'], TAction['payload']>
> = (payload: TAction['payload']) => TAction;
```

I'm not sure how to get the `GenericActionCreator` type to only accept an `ActionWithPayload` type as its argument since it also requires two arguments.

Goal is to get a type to use like this:

```js
type SetLoggedIn = GenericActionCreator<SetLoggedInAction>;
```

And use it in my function definition like so:

```js
export const setLoggedIn: SetLoggedIn = payload => ({
  type: 'SET_LOGGED_IN',
  payload
});
```

I have seen other ways of typing the function (e.g., [How to type Redux actions and Redux reducers in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35482241/how-to-type-redux-actions-and-redux-reducers-in-typescript)), but I'd like to try for this solution if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work as you've created a circular dependency to the `TAction`:

`TAction extends ActionWithPayload<TAction['type'], TAction['payload']>`

As you don't set any specific action type or payload it's enough to tell TS that `TAction` extends any kind of `ActionWithPayload`.

The following fix should do the trick for you:

```
type GenericActionCreator<TAction extends ActionWithPayload<string, any>> = 
    (payload: TAction['payload']) => TAction
```

Comment: Tried that, get `Parameter 'payload' implicitly has an 'any' type.` from the line `export const setLoggedIn: SetLoggedIn = payload => ...`

Comment: Cannot reproduce on my side (already have `"noImplicitAny": true` in ts config). Could you please let me know what's you TS version, @types/redux version and share contents of the tsconfig file?