how can solve 'action' is of type 'unknown'. in vs code?
How can I solve this error msg?
I change to add action on import or no action on import. that still cannot be solve. Thank you. I use vs code to do and i want to msg.This middleware intercepts actions to check if they indicate a rejected or fulfilled async operation.
If the action type ends with /rejected, it dispatches an error notification.
If the action type ends with /fulfilled, it dispatches a success notification.
It ensures that the action is passed to the next middleware or reducer in the Redux chain.
import {
  showNotification,
  NotificationType,
} from "../slices/notificationSlice";

export const axiosMiddleware: Middleware =
  ({ dispatch }) =>
  (next) =>
  async (action) => {
    if (action.type.endsWith("/rejected")) {
      const errorMessage = action.payload?.message || "An error occurred!";

      dispatch(
        showNotification({
          type: NotificationType.Error,
          message: errorMessage,
        })
      );
    } else if (action.type.endsWith("/fulfilled")) {
      const successMessage = action.payload?.message || "Sucess!";

      dispatch(
        showNotification({
          type: NotificationType.Success,
          message: successMessage,
        })
      );
    }

    return next(action);
  };

error msg:
TS18046: 'action' is of type 'unknown'.
     9 |   (next) =>
    10 |   async (action) => {
  > 11 |     if (action.type.endsWith("/rejected")) {
       |         ^^^^^^
    12 |       const errorMessage = action.payload?.message || "An error occurred!";
    13 |
    14 |       dispatch(

ERROR in src/api/middleware.ts:12:28
TS18046: 'action' is of type 'unknown'.
    10 |   async (action) => {
    11 |     if (action.type.endsWith("/rejected")) {
  > 12 |       const errorMessage = action.payload?.message || "An error occurred!";
       |                            ^^^^^^
    13 |
    14 |       dispatch(
    15 |         showNotification({

ERROR in src/api/middleware.ts:20:16
TS18046: 'action' is of type 'unknown'.
    18 |         })
    19 |       );
  > 20 |     } else if (action.type.endsWith("/fulfilled")) {
       |                ^^^^^^
    21 |       const successMessage = action.payload?.message || "Sucess!";  
    22 |
    23 |       dispatch(

ERROR in src/api/middleware.ts:21:30
TS18046: 'action' is of type 'unknown'.
    19 |       );
    20 |     } else if (action.type.endsWith("/fulfilled")) {
  > 21 |       const successMessage = action.payload?.message || "Sucess!";  
       |                              ^^^^^^
    22 |
    23 |       dispatch(
    24 |         showNotification({



The error means you need to define types of actions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35482241/how-to-type-redux-actions-and-redux-reducers-in-typescript - the top rated answer here may answer your question
